# Is there a way to write loop output to a file?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I've written this code:

```
for i in range(0, 3):
    for g in range(1, 4):
        if i+1==g:
            a = f'''r{g} = {list(df.iloc[i])}'''
            with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
                f.write(f'''{a}''')
```

This is the output I'm expecting:

```
r1 = ['kane', 'grealish', 'sancho', 'sterling']
r2 = ['foden', 'mount', 'bellingham', 'reece']
r3 = ['trippier', 'stones', 'walker', 'coady']
```

However, I'm only getting
`r3 = ['trippier', 'stones', 'walker', 'coady']`

How do I rectify this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Opening a file in `w` mode erases the existing contents.  So you're erasing the file each time through the loop.

Comment: Use `a` instead of `w` when opening a file in order to *append*.

Comment: Just a heads up that repeatedly opening and closing a file in a tight loop like this is rather inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
```

with

```
with open('output.txt', 'a') as f:
```

---

##use append when you open the file.